# If a version of GCH holds for Chang's $\kappa$-constructibility, does a version of GCH hold for $L_{\infty}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In C.C. Chang's paper "Sets Constructible Using $L_{\kappa \kappa}$" one can "deduce a version of the GCH, theorem VI [(iv)--my comment], assuming that all sets are $\kappa$-constructible."  Now $L_{\infty}$ is Goedel's constructible universe in $\mathcal{L}_{\infty \infty}$.  In his answer to the MathOverflow question "Goedel's Constructible Universe in Infinitary Logics", Prof Hamkins proves the following:

$L_{\infty}$=V.

Since this is tantamount to saying that 'all sets are $\infty$-constructible', can one deduce (as one can if all sets are assumed to be $\kappa$-constructible) that a version of GCH holds for $L_{\infty}$ (=V)?  If so, what version of GCH would this be?  If not, why does a version of GCH hold for the assumption that all sets are $\kappa$-constructible while for $L_{\infty}$=V the GCH is independent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that (choice holds and) $\mathrm{V}=C^\kappa$, we can prove the version of $\mathsf{GCH}$ stated in the paper, that for every $\nu>1$, $$2^{\nu^{<\kappa}}=(\nu^{<\kappa})^+,$$ since we can adapt the proof of $\mathsf{GCH}$ in $L$.

That argument depends on *condensation*, and the appropriate version of condensation is given in Theorem V of the paper, that $\kappa$-elementary substructures of initial segments of $C^\kappa$ that contain $\kappa$ as an element are themselves isomorphic to initial segments of $C^\kappa$.

This is used to bound the number of subsets of a cardinal $\lambda$ simply because any such subset should appear in an initial segment $C^\kappa_\eta$ of $C^\kappa$ where $\eta$ is not too large relative to $\lambda$ (as appropriate versions of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem allow us to form "small" $\kappa$-elementary substructures). This gives us an upper bound on $2^\lambda$ in terms of the sizes of the initial stages $C^\kappa_\eta$. In turn, these sizes are bounded in terms of ($\eta$ and) the number possible formulas in the language. The latter number depends explicitly on $\kappa$.

It is then an easy matter to find cardinals $\lambda$ (that depend on $\kappa$) where this upper bound is realized, and this is what leads to the trace of $\mathsf{GCH}$ stated in the paper (in Theorem VI.(iv), as you indicate).

Note however that no version of this argument survives in $C^\infty=\mathrm{V}$, since there is no bound on the number of formulas in the language, so there is no *a priori* bound on the sizes of the initial segments $C^\infty_\eta$. In fact, it is consistent that $\mathsf{GCH}$ fails everywhere in $\mathrm{V}$.

---

Using pcf techniques, Shelah has [found](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809200) (what one could argue is) a version of $\mathsf{GCH}$ that actually holds provably in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, namely:

> **Theorem** (Shelah)**.** For $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ infinite cardinals, let $\lambda^{[\kappa]}$ denote the smallest possible size of a family $\mathcal F$ of $\kappa$-sized subsets of $\lambda$ such that *any* $\kappa$-sized subset of $\lambda$ is contained in the union of fewer than $\kappa$ many members of $\mathcal F$.
>
> For any uncountable strong limit cardinal $\mu$, it is the case that for any $\lambda\ge\mu$ there is a $\theta<\mu$ such that *for all* $\kappa\in[\theta,\mu]$, we have  $$ \lambda^{[\kappa]}=\lambda. $$

Note however that this is far from the standard formulations of fragments of $\mathsf{GCH}$, and the known proofs of this result are delicate combinatorial arguments that do not relate to $\mathcal L_{\infty\infty}$ or appeal to either the fact that $\mathrm{V}=C^\infty$, or to adaptations of the condensation argument discussed above.

Comment: (As an additional obstacle, note that there is no reasonable version of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem for $\mathcal L_{\infty,\infty}$, so we cannot expect any decent analogues of the condensation argument, even if we give up on the issue of bounding the sizes of the initial segments $C^\infty_\eta$.)

Comment: Very nice answer.  Very helpful.

Comment: Does Shelah's result imply Chang's VI(iv)? Are they in any way interrelated?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. But $\mathsf{GCH}$ is too basic. Plus, it is not that $C^\kappa$ satisfies the trace of $\mathsf{GCH}$ described, but rather that it does *if* $\mathrm{V}=C^\kappa$. If under this assumption, the model $C^\kappa$ possessed combinatorial properties of the kind $L$ exhibits (square, for instance), I bet they can be explained combinatorially via other Shelah results. (Just as we can now essentially explain the presence of diamond sequences in $L$.)

Comment: If there is no reasonable version of the Lowenhein-Skolem theorem for $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$, then what does this say about L$_\infty$ = V since V is supposed to be a model of ZFC, a first-order theory where a reasonable version of the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem is supposed to hold (or is this a silly way of looking at things)?

Comment: The version that holds in $\mathrm {V}$ is for first - order logic, not for this infinitary logic.

Comment: That comment is very helpful. Thanks

Comment: You say that "Assuming that (choice holds and) $V=C_\kappa$, we can prove the version of GCH stated in the paper". The paper doesn't explicitly mention AC at this point, do you think it was implicitly assumed since this result is a consequence of thm V which requires some AC?